# how to create a delegate for an extension?

Tags: c#

I would like to create a method that is able to use several extension I created on a Vector class (MathNet). For instance, I've got the Vector extension:

```
public static bool IsNaN(this  Vector<double> m)
    {
        int i = Array.IndexOf(m.ToArray(), double.NaN);
        bool b = (i == -1);
        b = !b;
        return b;
    }
```

I would like to be able to use this extension AS A PARAMETER. For instance, I would like to write something like:

```
         public static Vector<double> ApplyExtension(this Matrix<double> x, VectorExtension myOperation)
    {
        Vector<double> res = new DenseVector(x.ColumnCount, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            res[i] = x.Row(i).myOperation();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Of course, "VectorExtension" is not a well defined type. I tried to create a deleguate:

```
public delegate double VectorExtension(this Vector<double> d);
```

But, it doesn't work. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Vector<TResult> ApplyExtension<T, TResult>(this Matrix<T> x, Func<Vector<T>, TResult> myOperation)
{
   var res = new DenseVector(x.ColumnCount, 0);
   for (int i = 0; i < x.ColumnCount; i++)
   {
       res[i] = myOperation(x.Row(i));
   }
   return res;
}
```

now you can use method group syntax

```
matrix.ApplyExtension(VectorExtensions.IsNaN);
```

or wrap cal into another lambda

```
matrix.ApplyExtension(vector => vector.IsNaN());
```

Comment: There are some inconsistancies here.  You made it generic, but didn't use the generic argument.  `res` is also a `Vector<bool>` but the return type is `Vector<double>`.  Perhaps they should all be `Vector<T>`, along with the arguments to the function?

Comment: If you're going to make it fully generic it looks like you'll need to generic arguments, a `TSource` and a `TResult`, since he's doing a mapping here.

Comment: @Servy thank you very much for comments. I will add mapping. First I thought he was doing some flattening. It's hard to correct also OPs inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate doesn't need to know or care that the method provided to it is an extension method.  There is no way you can *force* the method provided to it to be an extension method either.

The extension method is, under the hood, just another static method; tread it accordingly:

```
public static Vector<double> Apply(this Matrix<double> x
    , Func<Vector<double>, double> myOperation)
{ }
```

You would then call it like:

```
myMatrix.Apply(VectorExtensions.SomeOperation);
```